# Javascript: Displaying different color for each greeting message

Tags: javascript

In my javascript program I am trying to generate different background color for each greeting message and for that I have used randomColor to apply background color but it's not working. Can anyone tell me where it's wrong.

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>trail6</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>

    var today = new Date()
    var curHr = today.getHours()

    if (curHr >= 0 && curHr < 6) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'What are you doing that early?';
    } else if (curHr >= 6 && curHr < 12) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Good Morning';
    } else if (curHr >= 12 && curHr < 17) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Good Afternoon';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Good Evening';
    }

    var colors = ["#D3FFA3", "#FFF8A7", "#FFBC98", "#FF9A95","#B6FDFF", "#A8FFC1", "#B6FF99"];
    var randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];    
    document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = colors[randomColor];

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign `randomColor`, you're **already** accessing the `colors` array; `randomColor` gets set to the hex code.

As such, you simply need to set the background colour to the stored hex code directly with `document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = randomColor` instead of `document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = colors[randomColor]`.

This can be seen in the following example:

```js
var today = new Date()
var curHr = today.getHours()

if (curHr >= 0 && curHr < 6) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'What are you doing that early?';
} else if (curHr >= 6 && curHr < 12) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Good Morning';
} else if (curHr >= 12 && curHr < 17) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Good Afternoon';
} else {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Good Evening';
}

var colors = ["#D3FFA3", "#FFF8A7", "#FFBC98", "#FF9A95", "#B6FDFF", "#A8FFC1", "#B6FF99"];
var randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = randomColor;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at last line

document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = colors[randomColor];

change it like this

document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = randomColor;

Just tested and seems to work fine

[debugger snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWetG.jpg)